# Can't rebuild datepicker for generated html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After generating new `html` content I do:

```
var el_1 = $('.index_1').html();

$('#payment_block_content').html(el_1);
```

this `el_1` has a data field:

```
<input class="datepicker form-control hasDatepicker" id="id_date" name="date" type="text" />
```

How can I refresh this datepicker? Next I try:

```
$("#id_date").on('focus', function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting HTML you can directly initialize `.datepicker()`.

Additionally you need to remove *hasDatepicker* CSS class as its internally use by jQuery UI component to identify that `.datepicker()` is applied to the element.

```
$('#payment_block_content').html(el_1);
$("#id_date").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
```

```js
var html = '<input class="datepicker form-control" id="id_date1" name="date" type="text" />';
$(document.body).append(html);
$("#id_date1").datepicker(); 


var html2 = '<input class="datepicker form-control hasDatepicker" id="id_date2" name="date" type="text" />';
$(document.body).append(html2);
$("#id_date2").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @СергейПотапов, Updated answer

Comment: hm.. i use `.html(el_1)` when need use  `.append(el_1)` So ty for your snswer